# Significance of context name in snmpv3

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

Snmpv3 is a secured protocol compared to Snmpv2 and Snmpv1. But I dont understand what is the use of context name.We already have an user name and also authentication and privacy passwords which provide a security level. Someone using a wireshark cannot identify it as it is sent through encrypted form. So what is the use of context name in Snmpv3?

Answer (score 7):

The `contextName` and `contextEngineID` parameters allow multiple versions of the same MIB objects to be made available by a single SNMPv3 engine, as if you have multiple agents running on the same IP address and port. These are distinguished from one another by `contextName` and `contextEngineID`, where otherwise they would have had a different address and/or port. One reason for this could be that you have a master agent with multiple sub-agents and the sub-agents have some overlap. Another reason would be a proxy agent: for example, a manager that only speaks SNMPv3 and devices than only speak SNMPv1 could use a multi-lingual proxy at a single address/port and use the `contextName` and `contextEngineID` to identify devices. The proxy here would map the `contextName` and `contextEngineID` to device address/port and translate/forward requests to the devices and responses back to the manager.